# Out of bounds exception in output but runs what I want it to do

Tags: arrays, exception, split, java.util.scanner, indexoutofboundsexception

My code is as such:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    String name;
    int population;
    String[] tokens;
    FileReader fin = new FileReader("Test.txt");

    Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);

    src.useDelimiter(",");

    while (src.hasNextLine())
    {
        if (src.hasNext())
        {
            tokens = src.nextLine().split(",\\s");
            name = tokens[0];
            population = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].trim());
            System.out.printf("Name:%-15s  %-15d\n", name, population);
        } else
        {
            String str = src.next();
            if (str.equals(""))
            {
                break;
            } else
            {
                System.out.println("File format error.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("end");
    fin.close();
}
```

In my test file, I just have a state's name followed by a comma, a space, the population, and possibly a random space after the population. My output results as

> .....
>   Name:Virginia         7100702
>   Name:Washington       5908684
>   Name:West Virginia    1813077
>   Name:Wisconsin        5371210
>   Name:Wyoming          495304
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>       at javatesters.JavaTesters.main(JavaTesters.java:35)
>   Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

The end of my test file is

> Virginia         7100702
>   Washington       5908684
>   West Virginia    1813077
>   Wisconsin        5371210
>   Wyoming          495304
>
> Total Apportionment Population    281424177              435

And I want the blank line to indicate the end of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your scanner gets down to a line that doesn't include a ", ", that `split(",\\s")` call splits it into just one string. So, when you access `tokens[1]`, you're going out of bounds of the array. There are lots of ways to work around this. One approach (though not the cleanest) would be to check to make sure `tokens` has two elements before you use it.

Comment: But shouldn't the while(hasNextLine()) see the blank link as the end of file

Comment: Nope. The Scanner's cursor is pointing to the beginning of that blank line. You ask "Scanner, do you have another line?" The Scanner says "I sure do." The `hasNext()` condition in your if statement passes, too, so you're not making it into that else clause.